# Sometimes links are not clickable

Tags: html, css, z-index

Sometimes the links under the `<div>` element of the header cart are not clickable in the cart menu of my website.

HTML:

```
<div class="shopping-cart-btn">
    <a href="https://domain.tld/cart">View Cart</a>
    <a href="https://domain.tld/checkout">Checkout</a>
</div>
```

CSS code of the `<a>` tag:

```
.shopping-cart-btn a {
background-color: transparent;
border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
color: #454545;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
padding: 14px 20px 12px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
```

I tried setting `z-index: 9999; position: relative;` into the above class but it is still not working.
Also tried using `<span>` for the URLs but still, the links are not clickable.

To reproduce, go to **retracted** and then add any item to the cart, click on the bag icon on the top right side of the page and try clicking on both the links "VIEW CART" and "CHECKOUT". Sometimes it works but most of the time it doesn't work.

Check error
[image]

**EDIT: Please see mplungjan's comment for a possible solution as this question got closed wrongfully with unrelated solution.**

Comment: You need to share your html and JS code for us to see what's happening there.

Comment: check console error

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor HERE AT SO - when you have fixed the issue on your website this question is otherwise useless to other visitors

Comment: @LaljiTadhani There is no error in the console.

Comment: @mdhz added screenshot check now

Comment: There must be a pointer-event: none or an e.preventDefault somewhere

Comment: @LaljiTadhani It's a jQuery issue, nevertheless, I implemented the jQuery migration script to resolve those errors and warnings.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes there is pointer-event: none but removing that didn't solve the problem. But indeed there was e.preventDefault in a js file and commenting that SOLVED the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know who closed this question and added some unrelated topic to the original post but opening this question would be grateful so that I can write the solution for others in the case.

Comment: I closed it. An answer is not needed. You had code that blocked the link. You removed it. Not so useful to others., The dupe is how to disable a link - either using preventDefault or pointer-events. And that is what you had

Comment: @mplungjan Ah ok.

Comment: Anyway, great you found the issue